# how to put an li command into an canvas command in html5

Tags: html

Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

```
<div id="canvaslot" class="slots" style="text-align: center;">
    <ul class="hi">
        <!-- In reverse order so the 7s show on load -->
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie7.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie1.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50"  src="eddie2.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie3.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie4.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie5.png"</img></span></li>
        <li><span><img width="50" height="50" src="eddie6.png"</img></span></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to put these commands into HTML5 but in your question you are saying that browser does not support HTML5 canvas tag?

Comment: i want to make an trunch of html5b code in an canvas commnad html5 canvas command is it possible?

Comment: its ok i found  a way very simple t o do it just put an <br> and its working magic.